# Python Pandas, Resampling data with pct_change function

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issues with probably resampling my data using non standard functions.
Head of m data looks like this now:

```
Time
2009-01-30 09:30:00    84.9800
2009-01-30 09:39:00    85.0800
2009-01-30 09:40:00    84.9350
2009-01-30 09:45:00    84.8200
2009-01-30 09:48:00    84.9900
2009-01-30 09:55:00    84.6800
2009-01-30 09:56:00    84.7700
2009-01-30 09:59:00    84.2800
2009-01-30 10:00:00    84.2400
2009-01-30 10:06:00    84.1500
2009-01-30 10:09:00    84.2404
2009-01-30 10:10:00    84.1500
2009-01-30 10:11:00    83.9400
2009-01-30 10:15:00    83.8550
2009-01-30 10:16:00    83.9500
2009-01-30 10:24:00    83.9300
2009-01-30 10:25:00    83.9400
2009-01-30 10:26:00    83.9300
2009-01-30 10:29:00    83.7200
2009-01-30 10:31:00    83.5300
2009-01-30 10:32:00    83.4400
2009-01-30 10:33:00    83.4400
2009-01-30 10:34:00    83.4800
2009-01-30 10:35:00    83.4400
2009-01-30 10:36:00    83.5100
2009-01-30 10:44:00    83.6200
2009-01-30 10:45:00    83.6400
2009-01-30 10:46:00    83.6300
2009-01-30 10:48:00    83.5500
2009-01-30 10:49:00    83.5200

Name: spyo, dtype: float64
```

I want to resample the data using and hourly timeframe and should return the percent change of the value between 10:30 and 9:30 then between 11:30 and 10:30 etc.

```
Data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 964454 entries, 2009-01-30 09:30:00 to 2016-03-01 09:33:00
Data columns (total 6 columns):
spyo    964454 non-null float64
spyc    964454 non-null float64
spyv    964454 non-null float64
vxxo    964454 non-null float64
vxxc    964454 non-null float64
vxxv    964454 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
```

Comment: have you checked the pandas docs for resampling by time?

Comment: yes, they provide only basic examples of resampling by time using mean() or std()

Comment: there's a bit at the bottom or the page with `apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas 0.18 or newer, you could use [`Series.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html):

```
def percent_change(x):
    if len(x):
        return (x[-1]-x[0])/x[0]

ser.resample('60T', base=30).apply(percent_change)
```

which yields

```
Time
2009-01-30 09:30:00   -0.014827
2009-01-30 10:30:00   -0.000120
Freq: 60T, Name: spyo, dtype: float64
```

Without `base=30`,  `ser.resample('60T')` would resample the Series into 60-minute intervals (with minutes and seconds equal to 0). With `base=30`, the 60-minute intervals are shifted by 30 minutes. Hence the `Times` show `9:30` and `10:30` instead of `9:00` and `10:00`.

The first row shows the percent change from `9:30` to `10:30`. The second row, from `10:30` to the last time in `ser`, `10:49`.

The `apply` method allows you to aggregate the 60-minute intervals using a custum function. At the very bottom of [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) you'll find another example of `resample/apply`.

In Pandas 0.17 or older, [the syntax is a bit different](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) but the idea is the same:

```
ser.resample('60T', base=30, how=percent_change)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 100
index = ((pd.date_range('2009-01-01', periods=N//2, freq='2T'))
         .union(pd.date_range('2009-01-01 4:00', periods=N//2, freq='2T')))
Data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N,5)), 
                    columns='spyo spyc spyv vxxo vxxc'.split(),
                    index=index)
Data['vxxv'] = np.random.randint(10, size=(N,))

def percent_change(x):
    if len(x):
        return (x[-1]-x[0])/x[0]
print(Data.resample('60T', base=30).apply(percent_change))
```

yields

```
                          spyo      spyc      spyv      vxxo      vxxc  \
2008-12-31 23:30:00  -0.290145  0.116518 -0.767117  0.019722 -0.329499   
2009-01-01 00:30:00   0.957057  0.113174  0.331076 -0.179291  0.397392   
2009-01-01 01:30:00   0.412948 -0.366011  0.092585  0.455002  2.637628   
2009-01-01 02:30:00        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2009-01-01 03:30:00   0.169505 -0.901438  1.287304  8.042780 -0.189155   
2009-01-01 04:30:00  40.559281 -0.510897  0.316828  0.064967  0.236498   
2009-01-01 05:30:00   0.009669 -0.232149  2.055451 -0.210185  0.516835   

                         vxxv  
2008-12-31 23:30:00  7.000000  
2009-01-01 00:30:00  0.000000  
2009-01-01 01:30:00 -0.333333  
2009-01-01 02:30:00       NaN  
2009-01-01 03:30:00  2.500000  
2009-01-01 04:30:00  4.000000  
2009-01-01 05:30:00 -0.333333
```

Comment: It does not seem to work for me.  When I try to apply: hourly = Data.resample('60T', base=30).apply(lambda x: (x[-1]-x[0])/x[0]) to my whole data frame I get "Keyerror: -1" applying the code to a single column in the data frame does not work as well. Also, when I try to use regular resample by mean, everything works fine.

Comment: What version of pandas are your using?

Comment: I use Pandas 0.18.0 on mac OSX 10.10.5. When I use the code above to create radnom dataframe and resample it, everything works. When I use the same code on the initial dataframe it raises an error: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: I seems that I get the error because some hours miss the :30th minute in my DataFrame Index, logically I would like it to use previous datapoint for calculations i.e if 10:30 is not available use 10:29 etc.

Comment: The `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` can occur if there is no data in one (or more) of the 60-minute time intervals. I've edited the solution above to address this case.

Comment: The NaNs can be dropped, if you wish, after-the-fact, using `dropna`: e.g. `(Data.resample('60T', base=30).apply(percent_change)).dropna(axis=0, all=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing this problem then instead of using resample method for resampling data, I would suggest using asfreq method and set freq = ' Your resampling type' and then invoke pct_change().

```
Data_new = Data.asfreq(freq = 'BM') # where Data is your dataframe having a datetime index.
Data_new.pct_change()
```